# Run a stored procedure using select columns as input parameters?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a select query that returns a dataset with "n" records in one column. I would like to use this column as the parameter in a stored procedure. Below a reduced example of my case.

The query:

```
SELECT code FROM rawproducts
```

The dataset:

```
CODE
1
2
3
```

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyInsertSP]
    (@code INT)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PRODUCTS description, price, stock
        SELECT description, price, stock 
        FROM INVENTORY I
        WHERE I.icode = @code
END
```

I already have the actual query and stored procedure done; I just am not sure how to put them both together.

I would appreciate any assistance here! Thank you!

PS: of course the stored procedure is not as simple as above. I just choose to use a very silly example to keep things small here. :)

Comment: You can either put the select into the SP directly, loop through your select record set and call the SP each time, or create a user defined table type and insert into that and pass that to your SP.

Comment: I see... Could you give me an example as how I could do it the second option (loop through my select set and call the SP each time? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's two methods for you, one using a loop without a cursor:

```
DECLARE @code_list TABLE (code INT);
INSERT INTO @code_list SELECT code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code) AS row_id FROM rawproducts;
DECLARE @count INT;
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM @code_list;
WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @code INT;
    SELECT @code = code FROM @code_list WHERE row_id = @count;
    EXEC MyInsertSP @code;
    DELETE FROM @code_list WHERE row_id = @count;
    SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM @code_list;
END;
```

This works by putting the codes into a table variable, and assigning a number from 1..n to each row.  Then we loop through them, one at a time, deleting them as they are processed, until there is nothing left in the table variable.

But here's what I would consider a better method:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.code_list AS TABLE (code INT);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE MyInsertSP (
    @code_list dbo.code_list)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (
        [description], 
        price, 
        stock)
    SELECT 
        i.[description], 
        i.price, 
        i.stock 
    FROM 
        INVENTORY i
        INNER JOIN @code_list cl ON cl.code = i.code;
END;
GO
DECLARE @code_list dbo.code_list;
INSERT INTO @code_list SELECT code FROM rawproducts;
EXEC MyInsertSP @code_list = @code_list;
```

To get this to work I create a user-defined table type, then use this to pass a list of codes into the stored procedure.  It means slightly rewriting your stored procedure, but the actual code to do the work is much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

> (how to) Run a stored procedure using select columns as input
>   parameters?

What you are looking for is [APPLY](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-1); *APPLY is how you use columns as input parameters*. The only thing unclear is how/where the input column is populated. Let's start with sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Products', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Products;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Inventory','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Inventory;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Code','U') IS NOT NULL      DROP TABLE dbo.Code;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
  [description] VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  price         DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL, 
  stock         INT           NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Inventory
(
  icode         INT           NOT NULL,
  [description] VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  price         DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL, 
  stock         INT           NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Code(icode INT NOT NULL);

INSERT dbo.Inventory 
VALUES (10,'',20.10,3),(11,'',40.10,3),(11,'',25.23,3),(11,'',55.23,3),(12,'',50.23,3),
       (15,'',33.10,3),(15,'',19.16,5),(18,'',75.00,3),(21,'',88.00,3),(21,'',100.99,3);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX uq_inventory ON dbo.Inventory(icode);
```

**The function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnInventory(@code INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
  SELECT i.[description], i.price, i.stock 
  FROM   dbo.Inventory I
  WHERE  I.icode = @code;
```

**USE:**

```
DECLARE @code TABLE (icode INT);
INSERT  @code VALUES (10),(11);

SELECT f.[description], f.price, f.stock 
FROM        @code                    AS c
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnInventory(c.icode) AS f;
```

**Results:**

```
 description    price    stock
 -------------- -------- -----------
                20.10    3
                40.10    3
```

**Updated Proc (note my comments):**

```
ALTER PROC dbo.MyInsertSP -- (1) Lose the input param
AS
  -- (2) Code that populates the "code" table
  INSERT dbo.Code VALUES (10),(11);

  -- (3) Use CROSS APPLY to pass the values from dbo.code to your function
  INSERT dbo.Products ([description], price, stock)
    SELECT f.[description], f.price, f.stock 
    FROM        dbo.code               AS c
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fnInventory(c.icode) AS f;
```

This ^^^ is how it's done.